# On mouseenter on toggled class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use a little jquery to change the class of my menu when I resize my browser. That works but when I want to use mouseenter on the new class it doesnt work.

This is my code for resizing:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    windowWidth = windowWidth + 17;

    if(windowWidth < 780) {
        $('.menu_bar').parent().addClass('mobile-header');
        $('.nav_top').removeClass('nav_top').addClass('nav-left');
        $('.primary-content').addClass('responsive');
    } else {
        $('.menu_bar').parent().removeClass('mobile-header');
        $('.nav-left').removeClass('nav-left').addClass('nav_top');
        $('.primary-content').removeClass('responsive');
    }

});
```

This is the code for the mouseenter:

```
$(".nav-left ul").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
        }
    }, "li");
```

If I change nav-top to nav-left in my markup (when the menu has the class nav-left on document ready) the mouseenter works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  :

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowWidth = windowWidth + 17;

if(windowWidth < 780) {
    $('.menu_bar').parent().addClass('mobile-header');
    $('.nav_top').removeClass('nav_top').addClass('nav-left');
    $('.primary-content').addClass('responsive');
} else {
    $('.menu_bar').parent().removeClass('mobile-header');
    $('.nav-left').removeClass('nav-left').addClass('nav_top');
    $('.primary-content').removeClass('responsive');
}

$(".nav-left ul").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
    }
}, "li");

});
```